# Unity 3d | PostProcessBuild | How to add new run script to PBXProject from unity script while creating xcode project for iOS build?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game application using Unity 3d for iOS platform. When Unity 3d creates xCode project for iOS build, i want the xcode project with some predefined build phase and a run script. So what code should i write in PostProcessBuild to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question，You can refer to this link below:

https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/xcodeapi/src/stable/

I used it before because of work.

I downloaded it and made some code transformations. After I packaged the Xcode project test in Unity, I can achieve the following requirements:

1.modify Build Phases,such as add Run Script.

2.add Embedded Frmaework.

3.add System framework.

4.modify Build Settings.

5.modify Info.plist.

6.modify UnityAppController.mm.

Other reference code can test itself.

I put the code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVv8ZNIgvv6tAomf7oGt9zPI3IA4rB1P/view?usp=drivesdk), the downloaded XcodeAPI code needs to be distinguished from the Xcode API that comes with Unity. I added a namespace:Users.Custom.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_IOS
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
//using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
using Users.Custom; //
#endif
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



namespace ThirdSDKPostBuilds
{
    public class UserOnPostBuild: MonoBehaviour
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_IOS
        [PostProcessBuild( 900 )]
        static void OnPostProcessBuild (BuildTarget target, string pathToBuiltProject)
        {
            if (target.ToString()=="iPhone"||target.ToString()=="iOS") {
                Debug.Log("Start Xcode project related configuration of SDK......");
                Debug.Log(pathToBuiltProject);
                EditProj(pathToBuiltProject);
                Debug.Log("Complete the Xcode project configuration of the SDK！");
            }
        }
        #endif

        static void EditProj(string pathToBuiltProject)
        {
            string projPath = pathToBuiltProject + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
            Users.Custom.PBXProject pbxProj = new Users.Custom.PBXProject();
            pbxProj.ReadFromFile(projPath);
            string targetGuid = pbxProj.TargetGuidByName("Unity-iPhone");

            pbxProj.SetBuildProperty(targetGuid, "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET", "9.0");
            //pbxProj.SetBuildProperty(targetGuid, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "NO");
            pbxProj.SetBuildProperty(targetGuid, "CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES", "YES");
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreBluetooth.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "GLKit.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "AudioToolbox.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreFoundation.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "ImageIO.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "AdSupport.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "AVFoundation.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreMedia.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "Foundation.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "Security.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "UIKit.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreVideo.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CFNetwork.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "MobileCoreServices.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreData.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreMotion.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "EventKitUI.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "EventKit.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "MessageUI.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "Social.framework", false);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "Twitter.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreGraphics.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreLocation.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreTelephony.framework", false);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "MediaPlayer.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "QuartzCore.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "StoreKit.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "SystemConfiguration.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "AdSupport.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "Mapkit.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "Passkit.framework", false);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "Webkit.framework", true);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "StoreKit.framework", false);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "AVKit.framework", false);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "JavaScriptCore.framework", false);
            pbxProj.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "WatchConnectivity.framework", false);

            //add embedded framework 
            pbxProj.SetBuildProperty (targetGuid,"LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS", "$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks");
            string defaultLocationInProj = "Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/EmbeddedFramework/";
            string relativeCoreFrameworkPath = "";
            string[] commonFrameworkNames=new string[]{"EmbeddedFramework1","EmbeddedFramework2"};
            foreach (var frameworkNameTemp in commonFrameworkNames) {
                string frameworkName = frameworkNameTemp+".framework";
                 relativeCoreFrameworkPath = Path.Combine(defaultLocationInProj, frameworkName);
                AddDynamicFrameworks (ref pbxProj,targetGuid,relativeCoreFrameworkPath);
            }

            //add run script
            pbxProj.AppendShellScriptBuildPhase(targetGuid,"Run Script copy_test.sh","/bin/sh","./../Assets/Editor/copy_test.sh");
            Debug.Log("copy_test completed!");
            //add .dylib
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libresolv.dylib", "Frameworks/libresolv.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib", "Frameworks/libsqlite3.0.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libz.dylib", "Frameworks/libz.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libxml2.dylib", "Frameworks/libxml2.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libz.dylib", "Frameworks/libz.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib", "Frameworks/libsqlite3.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libc++.dylib", "Frameworks/libc++.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib", "Frameworks/libsqlite3.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            pbxProj.AddFileToBuild(targetGuid, pbxProj.AddFile("usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib", "Frameworks/libxml2.2.dylib", Users.Custom.PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
            //build settings
            pbxProj.AddBuildProperty(targetGuid, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-ObjC");
            pbxProj.WriteToFile(projPath);
            Debug.Log(" OnPostProcessBuild success!");
        }

        static void EditInfoPlist(string filePath)
        {
            string path = filePath + "/Info.plist";
            Users.Custom.PlistDocument plistDocument = new Users.Custom.PlistDocument();
            plistDocument.ReadFromFile(path);
            Users.Custom.PlistElementDict dict = plistDocument.root.AsDict();
            Users.Custom.PlistElementDict securityDic = dict.CreateDict("NSAppTransportSecurity");
            securityDic.SetBoolean ("NSAllowsArbitraryLoads",true);
            dict.SetString ("NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription", "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription");
            dict.SetString ("NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription", "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription");
            dict.SetString ("NSCameraUsageDescription", "NSCameraUsageDescription");
            dict.SetString ("NSCalendarsUsageDescription", "NSCalendarsUsageDescription");
            plistDocument.WriteToFile(path);
        }

        public static void CopyDirectory(string srcPath, string dstPath, string[] excludeExtensions, bool overwrite = true)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dstPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dstPath);

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(srcPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(path => excludeExtensions == null || !excludeExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path))))
            {
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(dstPath, Path.GetFileName(file)), overwrite);
            }

            foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(srcPath))
                CopyDirectory(dir, Path.Combine(dstPath, Path.GetFileName(dir)), excludeExtensions, overwrite);
        }

        static void EditUnityAppController(string pathToBuiltProject)
        {
            //Edit UnityAppController.mm
            XClass UnityAppController = new XClass(pathToBuiltProject + "/Classes/UnityAppController.mm");
            //Refer to the header file of the third-party SDK
            UnityAppController.WriteBelow("#include \"PluginBase/AppDelegateListener.h\"","#import \"ThirdDK.h\"");
            //add code:  [[ThirdSDK sharedInstance] showSplash:@"appkey" withWindow:self.window blockid:@"blockid"]; return YES;
            string resultStr = "";
            string newCodeStr = "    [[ThirdSDK sharedInstance] showSplash:@\"{0}\" withWindow:self.window blockid:@\"{1}\"];\n\n    return YES;";
            resultStr = string.Format (newCodeStr,"appkey","blockid");
            UnityAppController.Replace ("return YES;",resultStr,"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
        }

        static void AddDynamicFrameworks(ref Users.Custom.PBXProject project, string target,string embeddedFrameworkRelativePath)
        {
            string relativeCoreFrameworkPath = embeddedFrameworkRelativePath;
            project.AddDynamicFrameworkToProject(target, relativeCoreFrameworkPath);
            Debug.Log("Dynamic Frameworks added to Embedded binaries.");
        }


    public partial class XClass : System.IDisposable
    {

        private string filePath;

        public XClass(string fPath)
        {
            filePath = fPath;
            if( !System.IO.File.Exists( filePath ) ) {
                Debug.LogError( filePath +"The file does not exist under the path!" );
                return;
            }
        }
        public void Replace(string oldStr,string newStr,string method="")  
        {  
            if (!File.Exists (filePath))   
            {  

                return;  
            }  
            bool getMethod = false;  
            string[] codes = File.ReadAllLines (filePath);  
            for (int i=0; i<codes.Length; i++)   
            {  
                string str=codes[i].ToString();  
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))  
                {  
                    if(str.Contains(oldStr))codes.SetValue(newStr,i);  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    if(!getMethod)  
                    {  
                        getMethod=str.Contains(method);  
                    }  
                    if(!getMethod)continue;  
                    if(str.Contains(oldStr))  
                    {  
                        codes.SetValue(newStr,i);  
                        break;  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
            File.WriteAllLines (filePath, codes);  
        }  


        public void WriteBelow(string below, string text)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string text_all = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();

            int beginIndex = text_all.IndexOf(below);
            if(beginIndex == -1){

                return; 
            }

            int endIndex = text_all.LastIndexOf("\n", beginIndex + below.Length);

            text_all = text_all.Substring(0, endIndex) + "\n"+text+"\n" + text_all.Substring(endIndex);

            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            streamWriter.Write(text_all);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }

  }

}
```

Important code:

```
pbxProj.AppendShellScriptBuildPhase(targetGuid,"Run Script copy_test.sh","/bin/sh","./../Assets/Editor/copy_test.sh");
```

The final packaged Xcode project under the build Phases configuration is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxA2y.png

[image]

Comment: Hey, why can't you use unity's own classes like PBXProject and all ?